# pagebeforeshow not called in windows phone 7 phonegap application...?

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've done with my android,blackberry,ios phonegap application. Now I just port it through windows phone 7 application.
But here `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#preference', function () {
            console.log('pagebeforeshow-#preference called');
        });` this code never fire. I don't know if anything else I need for windows application with webview(phonegap).
I'm using phonegap 2.9.0 template for developing windows phone 7 application with wp7 sdk.

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
<div class="app" id="preference">
    <h1>
        Apache Cordova</h1>
    <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
        <p class="event listening">
            Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received">
            Device is Ready</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log('deviceready called');
    }
</script>
<script src="js/jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#preference', function () {
        console.log('pagebeforeshow-#preference called');
    });
</script>
```

It give me deviceready screen with "Jquery still loading at bottom message".
[image]

Below is the output window, where **pagebeforeshow** console log is not displayed.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: try  WinJS.log() instead of console.log(). or else got to **DEBUG > Windows > JavaScript Console** in the Visual Studio menus